# Enforcing all enum class types to have a common element using metaclasses

Tags: c++, enums, metaclass

In one of my libraries, I have a bunch of `enum class` types that I use for some `struct` / `class` and/or member function templates:

```
enum class Param
{
    Undef,
    P1,
    P2,
    P3,
    P4
};

enum class Type
{
    Undef,
    T1,
    T2,
    T3,
    T4
};
```

You get the idea. I make sure to manually insert an `Undef` element in *every* `enum`, which I use as the default for some templates:

```
template<Type t>
struct Container
{
    template <Param p = Param::Undef>
    void func() {};
}
```

Since I want **all** `enum`s in my library to have an `Undef` element, it would be great to be able to request that from the compiler. Basically, I want to be able to iterate over all `enum`s and inject an `Undef` element if it doesn't exist.

My question is, would that be achievable with metaclasses in `c++20`? If yes, what would the code look like (for example, using [Herb Sutter's](https://herbsutter.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/p0707r1.pdf) proposal)?

Comment: Metaclasses are not part of C++20. They weren't even proposed for C++20 adoption. Also, since metaclasses aren't finished being designed, it's not reasonable to ask about details like these.

Comment: I am aware that c++20 is not finished, but the proposal I linked to already contains some examples of useful things that can be achieved for `enum` types with metaclasses. I would expect that what I ask should be possible in principle, but I'm not sure whether metaclasses would work that way. I don't mind leaving the question open until a final design for metaclasses is accepted.